# Byte[] to ASCII

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, bitconverter

I received the contents of a text file returned in binary values:

```
Byte[] buf = new Byte[size];
stream = File.InputStream;
stream.Read(buf, 0, size);
```

How can I convert this to ASCII?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use:

string str = [`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It worked! It also works on ***any subset*** of the input buffer - using the variation with two extra parameters: [`ASCIIEncoding.GetString(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) (or without the third parameter for until the end of the buffer). (You may include this information in your answer, for a more comprehensive answer, though not explicitly asked for.)

Comment: Someone might need the backward conversion:  
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
```

But sometimes you will get a weird number instead of the string you want. In that case, your original string may have some hexadecimal character when you see it. If it's the case, you may want to try this:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
```

Or as a last resort:

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytearray);
```

Comment: Is conversion to ASCII lossy?  iow, `buf2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf))`  will it be the the same as `buf` ?

Answer (score 6):

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to reading a data from a stream to a byte array, you could let the framework handle everything and just use a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) set up with an ASCII encoding to read in the string.  That way you don't need to worry about getting the appropriate buffer size or larger data sizes.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    string theString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // do something with theString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Encoding.GetString Method (Byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) convert bytes to a string.

> When overridden in a derived class, decodes all the bytes in the specified byte array into a string.

**Namespace**:  System.Text
**Assembly**:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

**Syntax**

```
public virtual string GetString(byte[] bytes)
```

**Parameters**

```
bytes
    Type: System.Byte[]
    The byte array containing the sequence of bytes to decode.
```

**Return Value**

**Type**: System.String
A String containing the results of decoding the specified sequence of bytes.

**Exceptions**

```
ArgumentException        - The byte array contains invalid Unicode code points.
ArgumentNullException    - bytes is null.
DecoderFallbackException - A fallback occurred (see Character Encoding in the .NET Framework for complete explanation) or DecoderFallback is set to DecoderExceptionFallback.
```

**Remarks**

> If the data to be converted is
>   available only in sequential blocks
>   (such as data read from a stream) or
>   if the amount of data is so large that
>   it needs to be divided into smaller
>   blocks, the application should use the
>   Decoder or the Encoder provided by the
>   GetDecoder method or the GetEncoder
>   method, respectively, of a derived
>   class.
>
> See the Remarks under
>   Encoding.GetChars for more discussion
>   of decoding techniques and
>   considerations.